# How to Get this month,last month,last 3 and last 6 mnts amount to display in my dashboard

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT SUM(RequestAmount)
FROM Transactions MT
    INNER JOIN User_Heirarchy_Details UHD ON MT.UserID = UHD.UserID
WHERE UHD.ParentUserID IN (SELECT ParentUserID
                           FROM User_Heirarchy_Details
                           WHERE UserID = 38)
  AND DATEPART(MM, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())
  AND DATEPART(YYYY, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())
  AND MT.[Status] IN ('SUCCESS', 'PENDING')
```

I was getting amount data up to where userid=38 but when I try to filter with date from this step I'm not able to get the calculated amount and I'm having data related to date ranges.

```sql
    Datepart(MM,MT.CreatedDate )=dATEPART(MM,getdate())
AND Datepart(YYYY,MT.CreatedDate )=dATEPART(YYYY,getdate())
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have removed the C#, ASP.NET and SSMS tags as this question has nothing to do with any of them.

Comment: Why are you using `DATEPART` and not a date range with `>=` and `<` logic? The logic you have would return data for *this* month, not 3-6 months ago as well.

Comment: this code is for this month only not for 3 or 6 pls modify or give me any alternative

Comment: As I mentioned, use date ranges. Your implementation of `DATEPART` (which is bad for many reasons) is presumably leading you down a very bad rabbit hole.

Comment: *I'm not able to get the calculated amount and I'm having data related to date ranges* -- So what *do* you get? Also, side note, it's "Hierarchy". Eradicate such spelling errors from your code, they tend to backfire unexpectedly.

Comment: Please define "last 3 and last 6 mnts". If today is 4 January 2024 are your last three months from 1 October 2023 through 31 December 2023, 4 October 2023 through today, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This Month

```
AND DATEPART(MM, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(YYYY, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())
```

or

```
AND DATEPART(month, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(year, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
```

2. Last Month

```
AND DATEPART(MM, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(MM, DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE()))
AND DATEPART(YYYY, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(YYYY, DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE()))
```

or

```
AND DATEPART(month, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()))
AND DATEPART(year, MT.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()))
```

3. Last 3 Months

```
AND MT.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MM, -3, GETDATE())
AND MT.CreatedDate < GETDATE()
```

or

```
AND MT.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
AND MT.CreatedDate < GETDATE()
```

4. Last 6 Months

```
AND MT.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MM, -6, GETDATE())
AND MT.CreatedDate < GETDATE()
```

or

```
AND MT.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
AND MT.CreatedDate < GETDATE()
```

Comment: I recommend **not** using the abbreviations for datepart - it's much clearer to spell the part in full e.g month

Comment: Also, see @ThomA's comments above, `DATEPART` shouldn't be used. It converts all column values before comparison. A range check is much better in view of performance.